# typesetting according to the German traditions/standards for mathematical content

Tags: math-mode

There are German standards documents for typesetting of math and science. As far as I can tell, of particular interest are DIN 1304 (symbols in formulas) and especially DIN 1338 (typesetting of formulas).

As there are packages for citing according to German citation rules (DIN 1505), namely `din1505` and `dinat`, I was wondering **whether there are also packages facilitating German-style mathematical typesetting**.

(I understand that some of the German traditions cannot be automated and are left to the authors. Examples, for those who are interested: We don't use the ∴/∵ symbols nowadays (even though they seem to have originated in Germany), we always use centered dots (and never `\times`) for multiplication in arithmetic, we don't write things like "3(4)(5)=60" (found in many US textbooks, though not at the university level), and we use "~" instead of "∝" to indicate proportionality between two physical quantities. As for these examples, I do not know to what extent they follow from DIN 1338.)

An example given by [a relevant German Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formelsatz) would be that in German math typesetting, limits always appear below/above a sum symbol, though (disclaimer!) I have not verified this statement against the standard DIN 1338.

Comment: I don't know about those norms; but the reason why limits are typeset next to the summation symbol in in-line formulas is typographic: the limits above and below would irremediably spoil the spacing. If I have to choose between good typography and a norm imposed by unknown bureaucrats, I'd go with the former.

Comment: What do ∴/∵ mean? I think I have seen them, but never used.

Comment: @JuriRobl: Those are symbols for _therefore_ and _because_.

Comment: @JuriRobl As Peter says, they are used for "therefore" and "because", but in my opinion they should *never* be used, not even at the blackboard.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, I may have seen them in my Logic class. What symbols are used today? I would probably use `\Rightarrow` for _therefore_ but I have no idea what to use for _because_.

Comment: @JuriRobl: I think you should use `\implies` which has the correct math spacing instead of `\Rightarrow`.  Sorry I did not mean to imply that my comments were related to German typesetting, they were only to answer your question as to what those symbols mean. Those symbols are used in North America at least, although I rarely see the `\because` symbol.

Comment: @egreg I agree that some of those traditions can be argued about. Example: In German math, one generally encounters only round parentheses for matrices, even though it is clearly easier to hand-write the rectangular ones in a way that the result looks clean (people tend to exaggerate the bulge of round parentheses for matrices). Either way, it doesn't hurt to have a package that sets certain defaults - and that package can then still give you choices.

Comment: @user14996 really? I always learned in university to use `[]` paranthesis for matrices. At least the big ones, because you can't really add the additions to use simplex, and your Hessian matrices look strange if you use round paranthesis.

Comment: @JuriRobl Thanks for your input. I only saw round ones in my university materials and in originally German textbooks, but I guess either things have changed, or it's less standardized than I thought. The German Wiki article says "In der Regel verwendet man runde Klammern, es werden aber auch eckige verwendet" (= generally one uses round parentheses, but rectangular ones are used too), so I think my general impression is right. In the US I see more variation.

Comment: @Juri: I've been a mathematician for a long time, and I've hardly ever encountered square brackets. I've never ever seen them in pure math German lectures and literature.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Maybe my profs are just weird, I wouldn't be surprised by that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am German and I am writing my phd thesis at the moment. As far as I know there is no such package. You just use the right commands.

For example if you don't want to use the `\times` then simply use the `\cdot`. I highly recommend reading the book "LaTeX in Naturwissenschaft & Mathematik". Herbert Voss wrote it.